# GLFW Fails to Open Window in OSX

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I have the following code:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4); // 4x antialiasing
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

// Open window and create OpenGL context
GLFWwindow * window;
window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "OpenGL Testing", NULL, NULL);
if(window == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW Window.\n");
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
```

It works fine on my desktop on both Ubuntu and Windows, but it fails on my laptop running OSX. I thought it was an issue with the laptop not supporting this version of OpenGL, but it supports up to 4.1 with the video card.

I have thought that it may be using the integrated intel GPU instead of the nVidia one, but as I understand from what I have seen, GLFW will force the correct GPU to do the rendering.

If I change the context to 2.1, everything seems to work, but then the shaders aren't compatible.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** If all of the `glfwWindowHint()` calls are removed, the window is created, but the shaders are incompatible. I assume if these are removed, GLFW automatically chooses a context, which happens to be incompatible with shaders with `version 330 core`.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: The only error message that I'm getting is when is checks the window to be null and prints a message and returns. If I do switch the context to 2.1 or remove setting the context, I get an incompatibility error message when trying to load the shaders.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213874/creating-opengl-3-3-context-with-glfw-in-mac-os-x-10-9

Comment: Thank you! Realized I wasn't setting an error callback which I did, then leading me to the answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem came down to setting a forward compatibility flag in GLFW. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213874/creating-opengl-3-3-context-with-glfw-in-mac-os-x-10-9) led to the answer of making the following call:

`glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);`

This is also shown in the [GLFW FAQ](http://www.glfw.org/faq.html#41__how_do_i_create_an_opengl_30_context).